# Thread.sleep vs. TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep

Tags: java, sleep

If I'm going to have a call to have a Java Thread go to sleep, is there a reason to prefer one of these forms over the other?

```
Thread.sleep(x)
```

or

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(y)
```

Comment: Another option is `Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(s).toMillis())`

Comment: The proper syntax would be `Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(3))` if it were permitted.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

[`TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep-long-) will call [`Thread.sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) after validating that the timeout is positive. This means that as *opposed* to `Thread.sleep`, an `IllegalArgumentException` will **not** be thrown when the timeout is negative.

Other than that, the only difference is readability and using [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) is probably easier to understand for non-obvious durations (for example: `Thread.sleep(180000)` vs. `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(3)`).

For reference, see below the code of `sleep()` in `TimeUnit`:

```
public void sleep(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {
    if (timeout > 0) {
        long ms = toMillis(timeout);
        int ns = excessNanos(timeout, ms);
        Thread.sleep(ms, ns);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI:  Selenium project has a Sleeper method that doesn't require catching a exception when using it:  https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Sleeper.html

Comment: I agree. If you want to declare your sleeping time a constant that you can change later, say, from 1 minute to 10 seconds, one solution is `public static final long SLEEPING_TIME = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);`. This allows `Thread.sleep()`but maintains the readability advantage of `TimeUnit`.

Answer (score 17):

They are the same. I prefer the latter because it is more descriptive and allows to choose time unit (see [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html)): `DAYS`, `HOURS`, `MICROSECONDS`, `MILLISECONDS`, `MINUTES`, `NANOSECONDS`, `SECONDS`.

Comment: argumentative: I prefer the first - I want the thread to sleep, not the `SECONDS` or `MILLISECONDS` [:-)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: well, you can read it as *sleep for x `SECONDS`*, but surely it is a matter of taste. On the other hand, note that `sleep()` is `static` method on `Thread` - so one might argue that it isn't clear which thread is suppose to sleep (what does `Thread myThread = ...; myThread.sleep()` mean?)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Would be much better to be able write `Thread.sleep(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

Comment: The are not exactly the same, I've edited the accepted answer to highlight a functional difference (no `IllegalArgumentException` when the timeout is negative).