# How to send delay Response in efficient way to client

Tags: java, resttemplate

I have requirement to mock some of the service calls, but i need to send response after waiting a period of time.

I know i can do this by using `Thread.sleep(n)`, but i'm not comfortable to make complete thread to sleep for certain time.

So i'm look if RestTemplate has any method like `setResponseTime()` to set Response delay time. or can i achieve this by using any another external dependency ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use TimeUnit such as

```
- TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(timeout);
- TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep()
- TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep()
- ....
```

Or you can explore the interface ScheduledExecutorService, they have a method name scheduleWithFixedDelay.

Thanks,

Comment: i referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587673/thread-sleep-vs-timeunit-seconds-sleep

Comment: So anything is not clear not you? or you still have questions?

Comment: I mean i'm looking for method like this `setResponseWaitTime(long ms)`, so that i can configure, but this TimeUnit will internally call Thread.sleep() right? then what is the difference in using Thread.sleep() and TimeUnit class sleep()?

Comment: If you want, you can create your wrap method and hide the logic inside it. And yes for your question, TimeUnit is just an utility with more features and functions